# How to replace each element of an array with another array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, block

**MWE:**   Let us consider the following example.

```
L0=[[b,0],[b,b]], L1=[[b,b],[b,1]], L2=[[b,b],[2,b]]

S=[[0,1,2],[2,0,1]]
```

Is there any way the replace each element of S by L0 for 0 and L1 for 1 and L2 for 2 in S  to get S1 like in the image? 
[image]

Actually, I want a python program which will check: if the element of S is zero then it will replace 0 by the predefined 2D array and so on.

Comment: SO is not a "make me software service"

Comment: It is not an answer! @Netwave

Comment: So, how many such L- arrays do you have in your actual use case?

Comment: @Divakar: There are three L-arrays, but size of S is very large. Here I have shown small size of S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. We can first construct a numpy array that contains `L0`, `L1` and `L2`:

```
A = np.array([L0, L1, L2])
```

Next we construct a numpy array of `S`:

```
B = np.array(S)
```

now we have for `C = A[B]` (or `C = np.take(A,B,axis=0)` as suggested by @Divakar):

```
>>> C = np.take(A,B,axis=0)
>>> C
array([[[[b, 0],
         [b, b]],

        [[b, b],
         [b, 1]],

        [[b, b],
         [2, b]]],


       [[[b, b],
         [2, b]],

        [[b, 0],
         [b, b]],

        [[b, b],
         [b, 1]]]])
```

This is of course not exactly what we intended: we want to obtain a 2D-array. We can do this by first transposing (or `swapaxes`, like @PaulPanzer suggests) and then reshaping, we obtain:

```
>>> C.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,6)
array([[b, 0, b, b, b, b],
       [b, b, b, 1, 2, b],
       [b, b, b, 0, b, b],
       [2, b, b, b, b, 1]])
```

Since `4` and `6` of course depend on the size of the dimensions of `L0`, `L1`, `L2` and `S`, we can also calculate them based on that size:

```
A = np.array([L0, L1, L2])
B = np.array(S)
m, n = B.shape
_, u, v = A.shape
np.take(A,B,axis=0).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(u*m, v*n)
```

Like @DSM says, from Numpy-1.13, there is [**`np.block`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy.block) function for this purpose, and we can write it as:

```
>>> np.block([[A[i] for i in row] for row in S])
array([[b, 0, b, b, b, b],
       [b, b, b, 1, 2, b],
       [b, b, b, 0, b, b],
       [2, b, b, b, b, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it sophisticated process if the dimension of S is large, suppose 400x500? @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @MKS Why don't you try and you will see if it is a "sophisticated process"... [whatever you might mean by "sophisticated process"]

Comment: @AGN Gazer: I mean, is there any other way which can do the same thing quickly. May I use **bmat** for this

Comment: Instead of `transpose(0,2,1,3)`, `swapaxes(1,2)` is perhaps slightly more readable. Still, very nice answer.

Comment: While the listcomp isn't nearly as clean as `A[B]`, I think `np.block([[A[i] for i in row] for row in S])` (in numpy 1.13) is so much cleaner than the reshape that I'd go that direction.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: I used `3` instead, and replaced it with `b` afterwards.

Comment: BTW, use `np.take` for better performance with such repeated indices - https://ideone.com/hO8Cr8

Comment: @DSM You can kind of have both. You "only" need to persuade `numpy` that `A` is of type `object` with elements `np.array(L0), np.array(L1), np.array(L2)`. Then you can use `A[B].tolist()` instead of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of distinct building blocks `Li` is not large we can use the Kronecker product `np.kron`:

```
import numpy as np

L0=[[b,0],[b,b]]; L1=[[b,b],[b,1]]; L2=[[b,b],[2,b]]

S=[[0,1,2],[2,0,1]] 

S1 = sum(np.kron(np.equal(i, S), L) for i, L in enumerate((L0, L1, L2)))
```

Value of `S1` assuming `b = 3`:

```
[[3 0 3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 1 2 3]
 [3 3 3 0 3 3]
 [2 3 3 3 3 1]]
```